# Sql Group By Multiple Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping

I have this data

```
UserId   EntryDate       OutDate
100       1.1.2022      3.1.2022
100       2.1.2022      4.1.2022  
101       3.1.2022         -
101       4.1.2022      4.1.2022  
101       5.1.2022      5.1.2022
```

and i need this output

```
DateInfo     EntryCount     OutCount
 01.2022         1             0
 02.2022         1             0
 03.2022         1             1
 04.2022         1             2 
 05.2022         1             1
```

I've used MM.dd.yyyy format as default mssql format. I grouped by with multiple columns but result is not correct.
Could you help me about sql query

Comment: Which dbms are you using ?

Comment: That is not a valid date type, I will suggest storing dates in proper date time formats

Comment: I'm using mssql. I need to group by month and year info

Comment: Hi @SerdarYILMAZ when someone asks a question like the one about the dbms, then you can edit your question and add this additional info there. In that way experts from that fields will see the tag and help you faster... I have added the tag for you now...

Comment: I've understood. You are right. Thank you @VBoka

Comment: what date format is in use here? 2.1.2022 - is it second of jan or first of feb?

Comment: I've used MM.dd.yyyy format as default mssql format for easy understanding. It's first of february

Comment: *"I've used MM.dd.yyyy format as default mssql format"* Date and time data types don't have a format, so if you are using a format, it must be a string based data type and thus *not* a date.

Answer (score 2):

You need a calendar table to get stat on every period. You can use a conditional aggregation then.

Creating a sample calendar table for 100 month entries

```
create table calendar (
   d       date not null,
   d_year  int  not null,
   d_month int  not null);
with t0(n) as (
 select n 
 from (
    values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)
    ) t(n)
),ns as(
   select row_number() over(order by t1.n) - 1 n
   from t0 t1, t0 t2
)
insert calendar(d, d_year, d_month)
select DATEADD(month,n,'2022-01-01' ), year(DATEADD(month,n,'2022-01-01')), month( DATEADD(month,n,'2022-01-01'))
from ns;
```

The query, assuming the `EntryDate` and `OutDate` columns are of `date` type

```
select d_year, d_month,
    count(case when year(EntryDate) = d_year and month(EntryDate) = d_month then 1 end) EntryCnt,
    count(case when year(OutDate) = d_year and month(OutDate) = d_month then 1 end) OutCnt
from calendar
left join tbl on year(EntryDate) = d_year and month(EntryDate) = d_month 
               or year(OutDate) = d_year and month(OutDate) = d_month
group by d_year, d_month
order by d_year, d_month;
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use 2 queries `UNION ALL` to extract incoming and going and then `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY`  to present the information.

> ```
> create table EntryOut(
> UserId  int, 
> EntryDate  varchar(10),     
> OutDate varchar(10));
> ```

> ```
> insert into EntryOut values
> (100,'1.1.2022','3.1.2022'),
> (100,'2.1.2022','4.1.2022'),
> (101,'3.1.2022',null),  
> (101,'4.1.2022','4.1.2022'),  
> (101,'5.1.2022','5.1.2022');
> ```

> ```
> with movements as
> (select EntryDate, UserID IDin, null IDout from EntryOut 
> union all 
> select OutDate, null, UserID from EntryOut )
> select
>   EntryDate,
>   count(IDin) as In_,
>   count(Idout) as Out_
> from movements
> where EntryDate is not null
> group by EntryDate;
> ```

> ```
> EntryDate | In_ | Out_
> :-------- | --: | ---:
> 1.1.2022  |   1 |    0
> 2.1.2022  |   1 |    0
> 3.1.2022  |   1 |    1
> 4.1.2022  |   1 |    2
> 5.1.2022  |   1 |    1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dc04fe5123f18d62ee248455d07e342c)*

Answer (score 1):

First, as many of us say your date format is not correct.
Second, you need to aggregate every month for checking if there is entry or not.
Finally, you can sum up.

Try this:

```
WITH tab123
     AS (SELECT entrydate,
                outdate,
                CASE
                  WHEN entrydate IS NOT NULL THEN Dense_rank()
                                                    OVER(
                                                      partition BY entrydate
                                                      ORDER BY entrydate DESC)
                  ELSE NULL
                END e,
                CASE
                  WHEN outdate IS NOT NULL THEN Dense_rank()
                                                  OVER(
                                                    partition BY outdate
                                                    ORDER BY outdate DESC)
                  ELSE NULL
                END o
         FROM   test),
     entrytab
     AS (SELECT Concat(Concat(Month(entrydate), '.'), Year(entrydate)) tab1,
                Sum(e)                                                 e
         FROM   tab123
         GROUP  BY Concat(Concat(Month(entrydate), '.'), Year(entrydate))),
     outtab
     AS (SELECT Concat(Concat(Month(outdate), '.'), Year(outdate)) tab2,
                Sum(o)                                             o
         FROM   tab123
         GROUP  BY Concat(Concat(Month(outdate), '.'), Year(outdate)))
SELECT e.tab1,
       e.e,
       o.o
FROM   entrytab e
       FULL OUTER JOIN outtab o
                    ON e.tab1 = o.tab2
ORDER  BY 1;
```

[DB Fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=25bd72ec591114d719ec1a745d7a74df)

Answer (score 0):

I think following query may result what you want to do.

```
with table1 as (select UserID,EntryDate,OutDate from EntryTable),
table2 as (select count(UserID) as EntryCount, EntryDate  from table1 group 
by EntryDate),
table3 as (select count(UserID) as OutCount, EntryDate from table1 group by 
OutCount)
select table1.EntryDate,table2.EntryCount,table3.OutCount from table1
left join table2 on table2.EntryDate = table1.EntryDate
left join table3 on table3.EntryDate = table1.EntryDate
```

Comment: Thank you Tayfun or Sağolasın kardeşim :)

Comment: You're welcome
Rica ederim.